# How do you show the result of different drop-down options in Excel - sensitivity analysis?

Tags: excel

I have used CHOOSE in Excel to determine inputs for a model - the output is a NPV figure. I'd like to show what this NPV would be based on the various options in my model (1-5).

I figured I could use a Data Table with the NPV and the options across the top - this sadly does not work.

I am sure there is a straight-forward answer to this?

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.